# Is this rubber/PVC coupling a good enough for small torque (0.1 N.m)

Tags: control, brushless-motor

I am working on a project that involves speed regulation of a BLDC motor under no-load and load conditions. I wish to use another machine operated as generator, acting as load on the motor, as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8gvQIgOiGo).

The coupling used in this motor/generator arrangement looks handmade out of a rubber tube or somethhing. I am considering using it as an alternative to a flexible coupling. Purchasing an actual flexible coupling is not an option for me. Moreover, I need the coupling on an urgent basis.

My question is, can this arrangement (or something similar) be used to couple a 15W motor to a similar rating machine, if the rated torque is not exceeding 0.1 N.m?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, I use this method all the time for small robots, and actuators. I can find no information on the formal torque ratings, but I did find in a document called "[PVC Piping Systems: Helpful tips for Avoiding Problems](http://www.expert4pvc.com/Documents/PVC_Piping_Systems-PPFA.pdf)"

> The recommended best practice is to use a thread sealant (not a thread lubricant) and to assemble
>   the joint to finger tight plus one and one-half turns, two turns at the most. Finger tight can be
>   defined as: tightened using the fingers, no tools, to a torque of about 1.2 to 1.7 foot-pounds (1.7
>   to 2.3Nm).

I am assuming the pipe can withstand the torque of tightening threads. I suspect that tie pipe can withstand much more torque than that though.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The machine shafts are plain, having no thread. By tightening thread, do you mean something tied on top of the pipe to bolster its grip on the shaft?

Comment: No I mean that pvc threads are ment to be tightened to higher torques, thus it stands to reason that the pipe can handle this low torque, all you need to do is find some way to attach it to the output and input shafts.

Comment: In your opinion, is there any downside to using a small piece of pneumatic piping for coupling? I think that pneumatic piping being brittle and less flexible than rubber or PVC, may cause some irregular torque exertion on the shaft over the revolution.

Comment: For testing/research? No not at all for production or any kind of load? Use a proper coupling

Comment: For research alone. So I guess I should choose PVC/rubber over pneumatic tubing?

Comment: Honestly I would try it out and see what works